# Placed Analytics code - Google still not displaying analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I had placed Google Analytic's code on [my site](http://www.startupsandfinance.com/) and it started tracking my site but from some time it has stopped tracking it. I went back and checked to see if I had removed the code by mistake but it is there and is present in the head. Can anyone please help me out in making my site traceable again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though someone (most likely using find/replace on the site's template code) made a mistake.

```
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.<a class="inlineAdmedialink" href="#"><a class="inlineAdmedialink" href="#"><a class="inlineAdmedialink" href="#"><a class="inlineAdmedialink" href="#"><a class="inlineAdmedialink" href="#"><a class="inlineAdmedialink" href="#">google</a></a></a></a></a></a>-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

Comment: Seeing the start and stop HTML comment tags for the tracking script above the actual snippet says to me some modifications to the template were made affecting your tracking code. I would get a fresh copy from Google Analytics and paste it in again.